# What constitutes a build error vs stats.compilation.errors or stats.compilation.warning?

Tags: webpack

I'm using Webpack 2 by the way - `v2.1.0-beta.25`

I am trying to provide useful error feedback to users of my framework but am struggling to work out what the difference is between these three items:

- build error
- stats.compilation.errors
- stats.compilation.warning

Build error seems to always be `null` even when I purposefully add an error.
`stats.compilation.errors` outputs the useful error that I need and 
`stats.compilation.warning` doesn't seem to output anything as far as I can see.

I have some code to illustrate my point:

```
gulp.task('javascript', () => {
    return webpack(webpackConfig, (err, stats) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to create a production build. Reason:');
            [err].forEach(er => {
                console.log(er.message || er);
                console.log();
            });
            process.exit(1);
        }

        if (stats.compilation.errors && stats.compilation.errors.length) {
            console.log(stats.compilation.warnings.toString());
        }

        if (stats.compilation.warnings && stats.compilation.warnings.length) {
            console.log(stats.compilation.warnings.toString());
        }
    });
});
```

Please could someone clarify the differences?

Answer (score 1):

## Compiler errors (unrecoverable)

Webpack compiler errors are fatal, unrecoverable errors. A fatal error can be thrown by Webpack when the compiler options are being validated, or by a plugin, when the compiler options are being applied:

```
class GandalfPlugin {
  apply() {
    throw new Error('THOU SHALL NOT PASS!')
  }
}
```

## Compilation errors, warnings (soft)

These are mainly interesting and occur most frequently. Internally, Webpack applies [`webpack/tapable`](https://github.com/webpack/tapable) to all controller objects that need to perform some work. This includes the compiler and compilation instances. While the plugin instances are assigned to the compiler, most of their work is performed during a compilation.

One bit that's not obvious is that these are treated as soft errors and warnings. The compilation is guarded from synchronous and asynchronous errors: a compilation will always finish successfully, with or without errors (unless stuck in a infinite loop) and it will never break the compiler. Everything eventually gets pushed to `compilation.errors` and really this is the only thing that's available to authors to flag the compilation.